# The property 'Race.Vehicles' is of an interface type ('List'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, entity-framework-core

I have a class Race and I want to create table in Sqlite using entityframework core. I;m always getting this error:

> The property 'Race.Vehicles' is of an interface type ('List'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Is it some way to create table in db using interface as a property? I have 5 classes that implements my IVehicle property.
Here is code:

```
public class Race
{

   public Race()
   {
      Vehicles = new List<IVehicle>();
      RaceStatus = RaceStatus.NotStarted;
      Results = new List<IVehicle>();
   }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Year { get; set; }
   public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
   public RaceStatus RaceStatus { get; set; }

   public List<IVehicle> Results { get; set; }
   public double Distance { get; set; } = 10000;
```

}

Comment: EF works only with classes.

Comment: do a base class Vehicle which inherit from your interface